# Import Existing AWS CFN Template into AWS CDK for Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-cdk, terraform-cdk

I’d like to import an existing CloudFormation template. I came across a tutorial [1] to do this for CloudFormation. I was wondering, is there something similar for Terraform?

[1] Import or migrate an existing AWS CloudFormation template - AWS Cloud Development Kit (CDK)

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear why you can't do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, there is not such functionality.